# Preloader. "$.LoadingOverlay is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried already with muliple preloaders that can be found on the internet and with each of them I get the problem that they never show up. When I check what is going on, it always say that `$.LoadingOverlay is not a function"`
Been trying to implement this one but without any success
http://www.jqueryrain.com/?eKV1bCMa

my code:

```
<header>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/loadingoverlay.js"></script>
<script src="js/loadingoverlay.min.js"></script>

</header>
```

This one below I've tried to put into multiple places, under closing body, after opening body or even in header

```
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $.LoadingOverlay("show");

        // Hide it after 3 seconds
        setTimeout(function () {
            $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
        }, 3000);
    });
</script>
```

It never worked out ;l

I need some help with it

Comment: First you should not include both version of loadingoverlay, you could use only the .min file. Then you should make sure that the files are loaded, you can check this in the network console

Comment: @Hacketo Yeah, I know. I should have one version. I was just testing things out and copied here both version. Normally I use only one with min.js for lighter version type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the js minified in the js part and jquery 2.2.1 and it works like a charm, I think you should delete this
`<script src="js/loadingoverlay.js"></script>` from the header.

https://jsfiddle.net/o90psp2o/

I use the same function

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    $.LoadingOverlay("show");

    // Hide it after 3 seconds
    setTimeout(function () {
            $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
    }, 3000);
 });
```

Comment: tell OP that his code work is not very useful because it does not help

Comment: Thanks, It just worked out for me. At some point I had second jquery linked somewhere between html lines and it made it not red jquery at all x_ x